# Relation between the determinant and its inverse for solving a linear equation

Tags: determinant, inverse, tensors

I've been looking for a way to express the solution of

$A_{pi}x_i=w_p$

using the identity

$\epsilon_{pqr}det(A)=\epsilon_{ijk}A_{pi}A_{qj}A_{rk}$

by using the fact that $det(A)=\epsilon_{ijk}A_{1i}A_{2j}A_{3k}$ and end up with

$x_{i}=\frac{w_{p}A_{qj}A_{rk}}{\epsilon_{pqr}A_{1i}A_{2j}A_{3k}}$

However, I've seen somewhere else the identity $S^{-1}_{ji}=\frac{1}{2det(A)}\epsilon_{ipq}\epsilon_{jkl}A_{pk}A_{ql}$ and have begun to think this might be the identity I need to use in order to get the right answer. Could anyone shed some light on the correctness of my approach and the identity listed above? I feel like I'm missing a key relation between the determinant and its inverse (we assume here that the inverse does exist since $det(A)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

There's a matrix called the **adjugate** of $A$, with components given by:

$$\mathrm{adj}(A)_{ji}=\frac 12\epsilon_{ipq}\epsilon_{jkl}A_{pk}A_{ql}.$$

The matrix and its adjugate obey the property that

$$\mathrm{adj}(A)A=\mathrm{det}(A)I=A\mathrm{adj}(A)$$

and so when we have $\mathrm{det}(A)\neq 0$ we can divide through by $\mathrm{det}(A)$ and get that

$$A^{-1}=\frac{\mathrm{adj}(A)}{\mathrm{det}(A)}.$$

So in components we have

$$A^{-1}_{\;\;\,ji}=\frac{\epsilon_{ipq}\epsilon_{jkl}A_{pk}A_{ql}}{2\epsilon_{abc}A_{a1}A_{b2}A_{c3}}$$

and since $x=A^{-1}w$ we have

$$x_j=\frac{\epsilon_{ipq}\epsilon_{jkl}A_{pk}A_{ql}w_i}{2\epsilon_{abc}A_{a1}A_{b2}A_{c3}}$$

Comment: Oscar, much thanks! I ended up solving for the inverse by multiplying

$\epsilon_{pqr}det(A)=\epsilon_{ijk}A_{pi}A_{qj}A_{rk}$

by $A^{-1}_{pi}$ and then solving for $A^{-1}_{pi}$ which can then be applied to original linear equation to arrive at an explicit relation for the components of $x_i$ in terms of $A$ and $w$.